# @DateTimeFormat Spring not working on a Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I have a method where I want to take in some Dates which would be converted using the @DateTimeFormat annotations. Here is the method definition:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonUtil getAuditLog(
        @RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.Date_TIME) Date startDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "endDate", required = false ) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Date endDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page ) {
```

But I keep getting this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

So I tried this:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonUtil getAuditLog(
        @RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX") Date startDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "endDate", required = false ) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")  Date endDate,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page ) {
```

And that didn't work either.  Same error.  So I used that pattern with a SimpleDateFormat and manually convert the Date in my Controller.  That worked!  So why is @DateTimeFormat annotation NOT working?  This is in SpringMVC not Spring Boot.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: With date you should use `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE` with ISO 8601 format, `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)` for LocalDateTime

Comment: Do not use the terrible legacy date-time API. Try `@RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Instant startDate`. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) is an overview of modern date-time API.

Comment: Please focus on the question not your agendas for what API should or shouldn't be used. It's not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration xml file please include these lines i think that might be the issue .Because without them it will not identify these annotation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">
   
   
       <mvc:annotation-driven/>

   
   
       
</beans>
```

Leave rest configuration as it is just include these lines at required place.